# Swift: call function from another class to appear in same webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to call loadAddressURL() into the Webview from callbackHandler() in the xWebAppJS class. I have no problem calling the callbackHandler() from the ViewController but the opposite does not hold true.

I am basically trying to reload the page or any other page in the Webview from another class.

Thanks in advance! Sorry if newbie question.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

//... viewDidLoad() 
//... viewDidAppear()

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    let scheme = String(request.URL!)
        NSLog(scheme)

    //checks string if contains sequence
    if scheme.containsString("ios:JS.") {
        xWebAppJS.callbackHandler(scheme)

        return false
    }
        NSLog("Link was not tapped")
        return true
}

func loadAddressURL(URL: String) {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    Webview.loadRequest(request)
}
```

This is the other class that contains the callbackHandler

```
class xWebAppJS: ViewController{

class func callbackHandler(oScheme: String) {
   // I want to call the loadAddressURL() out of this function 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since xWebAppJS conforms to ViewController, you can just do `xwebAppJS().loadAddressUrl(Url:String)`

Comment: thanks for your input. This is the type of response I was looking for and I get no errors upon inputing this but I do get a runtime crash for "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil unwrapping an optional value". Any clue as to what I would be unwrapping and how?

Comment: I am guessing the variable URL in webView is an optional value. So to add a safety pin to it, you can do a guard let like this: `guard let URL = NSURL(string:"https://www.yourWebsite.com") else {
print("url was not found")
return }`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the class was called when I used your response, I have a whole separate set of issues apparently because what you suggested also throws an error. For that though I will give it correct answer. I may be asking the wrong question. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
This will be the answer ! 

**inside the class**
let requestURL = NSURL(string: "string URL")
self.loadAddressUrl(requestURL)

**outside the class**
let xWebAppJS = xWebAppJS()
let requestURL = NSURL(string: "string URL")
xWebAppJS.loadAddressUrl(requestURL)

func loadAddressURL(requestURL: NSURL) {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I was looking for something closer to what mn1 showed.